# Android Java Vibrate Via Bluetooth Paired Device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm looking a way to vibrate or make a sound sended via a paired device.
I just can't find anything... I have a android wear app that want to communicate with the paired phone can someone please help me

Thanks for All

Comment: Use a Broadcast Receiver and you are good to go :)

Comment: going to check it thanks for the information bro :)